# Can you use a singleton template in c++ using cython to interface with python?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I am writing a project in c++ and using cython to turn the c++ code into a python module. I was planning on using a singleton design template to store and hide a database. Additionally i was going to use static member functions to interface with this hidden database. Does anybody know if this design methodology is feasible in Cython? Additionally is there maybe a better strategy/template for coding this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The static member function idea does not work. But it is possible to make a singleton in c++ and than interface the singleton into python with cython. My git hub (https://github.com/drzeus99/cython-singleton) shows the code i used.

From my testing with this code, I found you absolutely need to use pointers for the c++ singleton. Additionally you need a public delete method so when python exits the c++ singleton will be deleted. When building and implementing the c++ singleton in cython(.pyx) code you also need to implement a singleton in python and store the cython implemented c++ singleton in the python implementation. The reason for the python singleton is the c++ singleton only produces a singleton at the c++ level but python does not enforce the c++ code as a singleton when producing new python objects. This leads to memory issues if two c++ singleton objects are produced in python and than deleted. The program crashes epically.